# Android N + mp4Parser error

Tags: java, android, gradle, mp4parser, android-7.0-nougat

So far I've been able to compile my app with `Android N` + `Java 8` without any problem. But now I add the library `mp4Parser` and it throws this error:

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.sched.scheduler.RunnerProcessException: Error during
>   'UnusedDefinitionRemover' runner on 'public
>   (com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.objectdescriptors.AudioSpecificConfig
>   -p_1_Lcom_googlecode_mp4parser_boxes_mp4_objectdescriptors_AudioSpecificConfig_,
>   int -p_2_I,
>   com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.objectdescriptors.BitReaderBuffer
>   -p_3_Lcom_googlecode_mp4parser_boxes_mp4_objectdescriptors_BitReaderBuffer_)':
>   com.android.jack.ir.ast.JBlock does not support transformation
>   'REMOVE', existing: com.android.jack.ir.ast.JExpressionStatement, new:
>
> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJack FAILED Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJack'.
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.sched.scheduler.RunnerProcessException: Error during 'UnusedDefinitionRemover' runner on 'public (com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.objectdescriptors.AudioSpecificConfig -p_1_Lcom_googlecode_mp4parser_boxes_mp4_objectdescriptors_AudioSpecificConfig_, int -p_2_I, com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.objectdescriptors.BitReaderBuffer -p_3_Lcom_googlecode_mp4parser_boxes_mp4_objectdescriptors_BitReaderBuffer_)': com.android.jack.ir.ast.JBlock does not support transformation 'REMOVE', existing: com.android.jack.ir.ast.JExpressionStatement, new:

Has anyone encounter this error? Any hint would be appreciated.

Edit add build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        //targetSdkVersion 'android-N'
        applicationId "common.josegonzalez.videotest"
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a" }

        // Enable the experimental Jack build tools.
        useJack = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.18'
}
```

Comment: please add build.gradle

Comment: Add build.gradle as requested @USKMobility

Answer (score 1):

Try using an older version of isoparser for Android. This one is recommended :

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.mp4parser/isoparser/1.0-RC-27

mp4Parser also need aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar to work properly :

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.7.3

Remember to include both of them in your build.gradle dependencies.